# We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now error on Add to cart in magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2

I am getting an error "**We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now**" when I try adding products to cart.
In exception log I am getting this error

```
main.CRITICAL: Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress' {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Validate_Exception(code: 0): Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\\Framework\\Validator\\EmailAddress' at /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Validate.php:244)"} []
[2020-04-27 06:50:07] main.CRITICAL: No such entity with customerId = 541 {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No such entity with customerId = 541 at /vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:52)"}
```

Comment: Please try with clear cache and remove generated files

Comment: @HiteshAgrawal tried multiple times. did not work

Comment: it seems that customer with id 541 is deleted , so go to quote table and remove entry with customer_id = 541 and then clear cache and generated folder , I hope it should work.

Comment: It is there, i checked in my backend